# CSS/Javascript - Div removing itself from Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently putting together a website for a buddy and myself. I purchased a template (mind all the silly placeholders and obvious space issues) to help get the ball rolling as I didn't have very much time available to put in to the project.

On the store section of the page you have that little gallery of products, when you scroll down a bit more it removes itself from the page (page jitters, clicking from store to about works funny). This is causing an issue with my Jquery waypoints setup. I can't for the life of me figure out what's removing it from the page when I'd like to keep it there at all times.
Any help is appreciated.

http://lovedrugfrontend.herokuapp.com/

Comment: So, to reproduce what u are telling, one should 1. **click store**, 2. **Scroll a bit** and then, notice **what?**. A bit confused. If you could elaborate

Comment: i cant see any problem on the page

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it either - Chrome `Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit)`

Comment: It's probably because you're using IE :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick fix you can try to give the

```
 style = "display:block!important";
```

to the 'team' class.
This will solve your issue.
This is just quick fix. Cant fix the issue without js files.